# How to change text colors prompt() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I change text features   in JavaScript prompt Method,  for example make some words color different or stronger.

Comment: You can't change the appearance of `prompt()` dialogs. You can, however, create your own data entry forms that work similarly (though not exactly the same).

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** - the prompt method is a built-in browser method - that sticked around from the 90's.

Save yourself from the 90's look and use a modal popup that you will create yourself with a `DIV` element, an `input` and a `button`